# Creating xlsx file using roo gem

Tags: ruby, roo-gem

I was using `spreadsheet` gem for reading and writing data to xls file. It was kind of easy. Now I need to work on xlsx file and I guess `spreadsheet` doesn't support xlsx files.

I found `roo`  gem supports `xlsx`.

For creating of `xls` file using `spreadsheet`, It was something like

```
book = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new
sheet = book.create_worksheet
sheet.row(0).concat %w[col1 col2 col3 col4]
```

For reading

```
book1 = Spreadsheet.open('Data/CA.xls')
read_sheet = book1.worksheet('sheet')
```

How to create and read using `roo`.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, `roo` supports both, but the projects are now split.

To have xlsx support you need to:

```
require 'roo'
```

To have xls support you need to require both:

```
require 'roo'
require 'roo-xls'
```

You can't create a spreadsheet excel file with `roo` it specializes on **reading** such file.

For reading then you need to:

```
require 'roo'

xlsx = Roo::Spreadsheet.open('./read.xlsx')

# get basic information about spreadsheet
xlsx.info
# get sheets
xlsx.sheets
# => ['Wow', 'greet1', 'greet2'] 
# get first row in the sheet Wow
xlsx.sheet('Wow').row(1)
```

For more information visit the [roo's github](https://github.com/roo-rb/roo) pages

### To create an excel file

To write an Excel file I would recommend [Axlsx](https://github.com/caxlsx/caxlsx)
gem.  I did not use it for some time now, but it used to be quite good.

There is whole buch of examples right at github - [example.rb](https://github.com/randym/axlsx/blob/master/examples/example.rb).

They are better than I would come up here so I'll post one of them:

**Edit** - missing output file

```
require 'axlsx'
p = Axlsx::Package.new
wb = p.workbook

## A Simple Workbook
if examples.include? :basic
  wb.add_worksheet(:name => "Basic Worksheet") do |sheet|
    sheet.add_row ["First Column", "Second", "Third"]
    sheet.add_row [1, 2, 3]
    sheet.add_row ['     preserving whitespace']
  end
end

p.serialize("example.xlsx")
```

Comment: How should I create an xlsx file then if I have to

Answer (score 0):

Exporting data with multiple XLSX spreadsheets single sort on Rails

```
ods.sheets

out_put = ['Info', 'Sheet 2', 'Sheet 3']

ods.each do |sheet|


   ods.default_sheet = sheet

     ods.each_with_index do |name, sheet|

       p sheet.row(1)
     end 
end
```